# Is it possible to use `or` in `when` section of `case` statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How to use `or` in `when` section of `case` statement?

```
DECLARE @TestVal INT
SET @TestVal = 1
SELECT
CASE @TestVal
WHEN 1 THEN 'First'--- this line
WHEN 2 THEN 'First'--- and this line
WHEN 3 THEN 'Third'
ELSE 'Other'
END
```

instead of using two above lines I want to use something like this:

```
when 1 or 2 then 'First'
```

Comment: There's actually nothing wrong with your case statement.  It is called a _simple_ case statement.  To do what you're asking, the case statement needs to be re-working into a _searched_ case statement (just like @MostyMostacho 's excellent answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN @TestVal in (1, 2) THEN 'First OR Second'
    WHEN @TestVal = 3 THEN 'Third'
    ELSE 'Other'
END
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) is the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
CASE 
WHEN @TestVal = 1 or @TestVal = 2 THEN 'First'
...
```